# Issue with scope and passing parameters to dynamically created event handler

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In the code below you will see that I am trying to define an event handler for `image.onclick` which takes extra parameters, I was declaring those parameters inside of the while loop hoping JavaScript defined scope this way but it does not. Basically all of the event handlers here are getting the very last value that I give to variables `id` and `section_id`. Any idea on how to handle a situation where i want to be generating these handlers dynamically?

```
function handlePicturesResult(){
    if (req.readyState == 4) { // Complete
        if (req.status == 200) { // OK response

            var el = document.getElementById('pictureHolder');
            while( el.hasChildNodes() ){
                el.removeChild(el.lastChild);
            }
            
            var tempObject = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            var pictures = tempObject.images;
            var i=0;

            while(i<pictures.length){

                var picIndex = i;
                
                var image= new Image(120,80);
                image.src = 'images/' + pictures[i].url;
                image.width = 120;
                image.height = 80;
                var id = pictures[picIndex].id;
                var section_id = pictures[picIndex].sectionId;
                image.onclick = function(event){
                    deleteImage(event,id,section_id);
                }
                
                
                var txtNode = document.createTextNode(pictures[picIndex.valueOf()].id); 
                el.appendChild(image);
                el.appendChild(txtNode);
                i++;
            }
        } else {
        alert("Problem: " + req.statusText);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yet another problem solved by [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)!

```
image.onclick = function(id, section_id){
    return function(event) {
        deleteImage(event,id,section_id);
    }
}(id, section_id);
```

The outer function is run at once (notice the parentheses with arguments at the end), and it returns the inner function, which keeps in its scope a *copy of the variables* as they are at that iteration of the loop.

JavaScript passes non-object variable by value, so by passing `id` and `section_id` to the outer function, you create a copy of them inside that function.  When you create and return the inner function, that inner function keeps in scope all variables that are in scope at the time of its creation (this is at the heart of [what a closure is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science))), including the local-variable copies of `id` and `section_id`.  The inner function, with its unique scope, becomes the event handler for that element.

Comment: sorry did not know how to i did now :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a closure.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

```
image.onclick = function(id, s_id){
  return function(event){
    deleteImage(event, id, s_id);
  }
}(id, section_id)
```

Scope in javascript can be defined within the curly braces of a function, which why having an outer function execute with arguments passed to it will preserve the value of these variables at the specific time in the loop you need them.

Without them, the values of id and section_id will always reference the value they have at last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic JavaScript problem that stems from lack of understanding about function scope. On this line:

```
deleteImage(event,id,section_id);
```

there is no reason that the parameters passed to `deleteImage` should retain the values they had *at the time* when the callback was created. The variables `id` and `section_id` are bound to the scope of `handlePicturesResult`; they are variables that exist within that space, and there is only ever a single copy of each. Thus, when the callback runs, it will use those specific variables and the values they currently refer to (from the loop's last iteration).

The solution is to get the variables into a scope that "saves off" their values every iteration of the loop. Functions provide the only such scopes in JS. I won't repeat the excellent solutions already provided. An alternative is to use jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for iterations, and you won't have this problem again:

```
$.each(pictures, function(i, picture) {

    var image= new Image(120,80);
    var id = pictures.id;
    var section_id = picture.sectionId;
    var txtNode = document.createTextNode(id);

    image.width = 120;
    image.height = 80;
    image.src = 'images/' + picture.url;

    image.onclick = function(event){
        deleteImage(event, id, section_id);
    }

    el.appendChild(image);
    el.appendChild(txtNode);

});
```

- Assumes `pictures` is an array.